# Are they any decent on-disk implementations of Java's Map?

Tags: java, collections

I'm looking for an on-disk implementation of `java.util.Map`.  Nothing too fancy, just something that I can point at a directory or file and have it store its contents there, in some way it chooses.  Does anyone know of such a thing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could have a look at the [Disk-Backed-map](https://github.com/aloksingh/disk-backed-map) project.

> *A library that implements a disk backed map in Java*
>
> *A small library that provide a disk backed map implementation for storing large number of key value pairs. The map implementations (HashMap, HashTable) max out around 3-4Million keys/GB of memory for very simple key/value pairs and in most cases the limit is much lower. DiskBacked map on the other hand can store betweeen 16Million (64bit JVM) to 20Million(32bit JVM) keys/GB, regardless the size of the key/value pairs.*

Comment: This is an accurate quotation from their website, but it must be wrong. It makes no sense for a 64-bit JVM to have smaller collections than a 32-bit JVM.

Comment: I'd guess the lower keys/GB is due to 64-bit addresses being twice the size of 32-bit addresses.

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for `key-object` based structures to persist data then NoSQL databases are a very good choice. You'll find that some of them such [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) or [Redis](http://redis.io/) scale and perform for big datasets and apart from hash based look ups they provide interesting query and transactional features.

In essence these types of systems are a Map implementation. And it shouldn't be too complicated to implement your own adapter that implements `java.util.Map` to bridge them.

Answer (score 6):

MapDB ([mapdb.org](http://www.mapdb.org/)) does exactly what you are looking for. Besides disk backed TreeMap and HashMap it gives you other collection types.

It's maps are also thread-safe and have really good performance.

See [Features](http://www.mapdb.org/features.html)

Comment: It looks nice on paper, but in my experience it's sadly utterly slow and not crash safe at all (even with `transactionEnable`).

Answer (score 2):

[Chronicle Map](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map) is a modern and [the fastest](http://jetbrains.github.io/xodus/#benchmarks) solution to this problem. It implements `ConcurrentMap` interface and persists the data to disk (under the hood, it is done by mapping Chronicle Map's memory to a file).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple EHCache implementation? The nice thing about EHCache being that it *can* be very simple to implement :-)

I take it you've ruled out serialising / deserialising an actual Map instance?

Comment: Yes, I've ruled that out.  I don't want ever to have to have the whole thing in memory.

Comment: Isnt EHCache payed ? Is there any free version

Comment: It's Open Source, so no license cost

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a relatively new open source solution to the problem, I've used it, and like it so far

https://github.com/jankotek/JDBM4