# local storage list implementation

Tags: java, list

Is there a implementation of List as a local storage instead of main memory resident in java.
Basically my application have to store a huge amount of data and i don't want to use the memory resident list implementations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are they any decent on-disk implementations of Java's Map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815633/are-they-any-decent-on-disk-implementations-of-javas-map)

Comment: I dont see a List implementation there

Comment: `List<T>` is essentially a `Map<Integer, T>` :) No, really, get the simplest key-value 'database' you can.

Comment: So what happens when i remove a element in between ??